# Run a command in background and another command in frontground in the same line

Tags: bash

I want to run 2 commands (command1 and command2) in the same line, where command1 starts a background process and command2 starts a frontground process.

I tried:

```
command1 & ; command2
```

But it says: "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'"

How could I run the 2 commands in the same line?

Answer (score 2):

`;` is not helping here. The control operator you need here is `&` after the first command (thanks [Nick Russo in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040212/run-a-command-in-background-and-another-command-in-frontground-in-the-same-line/26040317#comment40829035_26040317)):

```
command1 & command2
```

From [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.
>
> Commands separated by a `;` are executed sequentially; the shell waits
>   for each command to terminate in turn. The return status is the exit
>   status of the last command executed.

#### Test

```
$ sleep 10 & echo "yes"
[2] 13368
yes
$ 
[1]-  Done                    sleep 10
$
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, though it could be worded even more strongly: The & replaces the ; as the control operator:  "Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially", "If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell." http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: @NickRusso thanks for the comment, I added it into the answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(command1 &); command2
```

The the syntax `(command)` is creating a "subshell". You can read [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) something about it.

Comment: Why would you want to run the first command in another shell? I don't see the benefit about it in this case.

Comment: Oh mainly for clarity. I think it's more readable for a not so expert person.

Comment: Mmm yes, I agree it can be read more easily. Only that it is another subshell with all its meanings: variables set in the current shell won't be accessible, etc.

Comment: It depends: if you export a variabile in the main shell, you'll see it in the subshell. Anyway, in this simple case, I can't see any variabile problem.