# The 2nd command is not executed before terminating the previous one

Tags: bash, neo4j

I'm very new to bash. I'm running a bash script. It is supposed to start Neo4j and then execute a series of queries located in a file called "cypher.ex1". Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
./bin/neo4j console
./bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 123456 --file cypher.ex1
```

In order to use Cypher-shell, we should start the Neo4j service first. So, this line:

```
./bin/neo4j console
```

starts the Neo4j, so that cypher-shell can be used using the following line:

```
./bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 123456 --file cypher.ex1
```

The problem is that since `./bin/neo4j console` starts the Neo4j service, the next command (`./bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 123456 --file cypher.ex1`) is not executed unless I press the "Ctrl + C". If I press "Ctrl + C", the Neo4j service will be stopped and the following command will not be executed too (I get "connection refused" error). What should I do in order to start the Neo4j service and then run the cypher shell in this bash script?

I tried the solutions given in [Run a command in background and another command in frontground in the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040212/run-a-command-in-background-and-another-command-in-frontground-in-the-same-line). None of them worked for me. For example, When I execute the code with "(command1 &); command2" (As it was suggested in the proposed topic), my script is executed 2 times automatically. The first time command2 is executed and since the command1 is not executed I get "connection refused" error; The second time command1 is executed and command2 is not executed.

Comment: Also, in scripts you should always check to make sure a `cd` command worked before going on to do other things, or the rest of the script might run in the wrong place. See [this shellcheck error description](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164). (BTW, running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) can help avoid a lot of common mistakes.)

Comment: @Sorin No, it doesn't. I tried the solutions suggested in that topic. When I execute the code with "(command1 &); command2" (As it was suggested in your proposed topic), my script is executed 2 times automatically. The first time *command2* is executed and since the *command1* is not executed I get "connection refused" error; The second time *command1* is executed and *command2* is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

As it it mentioned in first answer in the Q/A you should exec the commands on this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
./bin/neo4j console &
./bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 123456 --file cypher.ex1
```

This will run `./bin/neo4j console` in background. So you need to take care about this process and stop it in case of need:

```
PID=$(jobs -l |awk '{print $2}')
kill $PID
```